# Why is my JSON request failing with AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

I'm accessing the [Clear Read API](http://api.thequeue.org/v1/) to extract the article text from a link, and the API works by putting in parameters into this URL: `http://api.thequeue.org/v1/clear?url=&format=` where after URL you could put, say, `http://www.nytimes.com/2013/03/25/business/global/cyprus-and-europe-officials-agree-on-outlines-of-a-bailout.html?hp&_r=0` and after format you'd put `json`.

It would then return JSON in the form of a status code, an `item`, and then within `item` the title of the article, its URL and the extracted article text.

I'm trying to interface with this through AFNetworking and AFHTTPClient (subclassed as AFClearReadClient) with the following code:

My AFClearReadClient class:

```
#import "AFClearReadClient.h"
#import "AFJSONRequestOperation.h"

@implementation AFClearReadClient

+ (AFClearReadClient *)sharedClient {
    static AFClearReadClient *sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedClient = [[AFClearReadClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.thequeue.org/v1/clear?url=&format="]];
    });

    return sharedClient;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    if (self = [super initWithBaseURL:url]) {
        [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    }

    return self;
}
```

and the following in my root viewcontroller:

```
- (void)addArticlesToQueueFromList:(NSDictionary *)articles {
    // Restrict amount of operations that can occur at once
    [[AFClearReadClient sharedClient].operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:5];

    // Create an array to hold all of our requests to make
    NSMutableArray *requestOperations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSString *key in articles) {
        // Create the request from the article's URL and the request parameters
        NSString *articleURL = [[articles objectForKey:key] objectForKey:@"resolved_url"];
        NSDictionary *requestParameters = @{@"url": articleURL,
                                            @"format": @"json"};
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFClearReadClient sharedClient] requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:nil parameters:requestParameters];

        // Create the request operation and specify behaviour on success and failure
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFClearReadClient sharedClient] HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            // Get the item NSDictionary from the JSON responseObject
            NSDictionary *item = [responseObject objectForKey:@"item"];

            // Get the values needed to create an article
            NSString *title = [item objectForKey:@"title"];
            NSString *URL = [item objectForKey:@"link"];
            NSString *body = [item objectForKey:@"description"];

            // Create and add the article to our list of articles
            Article *article = [[Article alloc] initWithTitle:title URL:URL body:body];
            [self.articles insertObject:article atIndex:0];
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Request operation error");
        }];

        // Save the request operation in an NSArray so all can be enqueued later
        [requestOperations addObject:requestOperation];
    }

    // Enqueue the request operations
    [[AFClearReadClient sharedClient] enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:requestOperations progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
        NSLog(@"Processing...");
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
        NSLog(@"Done!");
    }];
}
```

But whenever I run it I expected my table view to be populated (it gets its cells from RootViewController's articles array), but instead I get the following in the console:

```
2013-03-25 11:31:35.470 [19020:c07] Processing...
2013-03-25 11:31:35.471 [19020:c07] Request operation error
2013-03-25 11:31:35.476 [19020:c07] Processing...
2013-03-25 11:31:35.476 [19020:c07] Request operation error
2013-03-25 11:31:35.477 [19020:c07] Processing...
2013-03-25 11:31:35.477 [19020:c07] Request operation error
2013-03-25 11:31:35.480 [19020:c07] Processing...
2013-03-25 11:31:35.480 [19020:c07] Request operation error
2013-03-25 11:31:35.481 [19020:c07] Processing...
2013-03-25 11:31:35.482 [19020:c07] Request operation error
2013-03-25 11:31:35.488 [19020:c07] Done!
```

What exactly is going wrong? I've mulled over this but I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong. When I just used NSURLConnection one at a time (not nearly efficient enough for what I want to do) it worked, but I seem to be messing something up with AFNetworking.

Is it to do with my `requestParameters` variable? Am I making the request to the Clear Read API incorrectly?

Comment: from the [xcode-tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xcode/info): «This tag should only be used for questions about the Xcode tool, itself, not for programming questions for which you happen be using Xcode.»

Comment: what does the error object tells you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check, what the error object contains, but I think your base url isnt right, as it contains keys for get parameter, but those would be added from AFNetworking when needed.

```
sharedClient = [[AFClearReadClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.thequeue.org/v1/clear?url=&format="]];
```

should read

```
sharedClient = [[AFClearReadClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.thequeue.org/v1/clear"]]
```

to inspect the error, do

```
…
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Request operation error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];
```

---

you could also try to set the base url to `http://api.thequeue.org/`and than

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFClearReadClient sharedClient] requestWithMethod:@"GET" 
                                              path: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/v1/clear?url=%@&format=json", articleURL]
                                        parameters:nil];
```

if this happen to work and the other not I'd assume it is because of a limitation that is stated on the api's documentation:

> **Important**: The url query must always come first.

---

I re-created your project. Indead your frist code yield this malformed url:

```
 NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://api.thequeue.org/v1/clear/?url=&format=?format=json&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2F2013%2F03%2F25%2Fbusiness%2Fglobal%2Fcyprus-and-europe-officials-agree-on-outlines-of-a-bailout.html%3Fhp%26_r%3D0
```

and with my fix:

```
http://api.thequeue.org/v1/clear/?format=json&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nytimes.com%2F2013%2F03%2F25%2Fbusiness%2Fglobal%2Fcyprus-and-europe-officials-agree-on-outlines-of-a-bailout.html
```

what is technically correct, but the api is limited there, as url parameter isnt first.

Comment: I changed the URL as you suggested, but it didn't fix it unfortunately. As far as the error goes, it reads: "Expected status code in (200-299), got 500" (I believe that means a server error, but the API's server is up and running perfectly.)

Comment: the error should also contain the url. how does it look like?

Comment: The error doesn't contain a URL, I posted exactly what the console outputted.

Comment: the error has more information to offer than the localized description